# Why does Windows 10 show "Resume from Hibernation" on every boot though it was shutdown properly?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate, reboot, event-log

What I found in the event log is some information that apparently the system was reactivated from standby mode, but I definitely shut the system down regularly. This happens all the time. What is it, some faulty ACPI config?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Since [Windows 8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8), the shutdown is a logoff of the user + hibernation of the kernel/Windows services.

[image]

So booting is now a resume of the kernel/all drivers/services + login of a user. This resuming of services/drivers is much faster compared to a full boot where Windows has to start each service/driver again. So everything is fine. If you want the old boot/shutdown or dualboot with Linux systems, [disable fast Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html).

[image]

Otherwise you can't mount the Windows partition in Linux.

[image: http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/ximg_56731be792cd9.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.qF_roOiYB0.png]

Comment: That's it! I'm switching to Linux! I've been lied to for too long. lol I can't believe I am *just* learning this little fact... this explains a lot for me! +1

Comment: Another option is to hold Shift while clicking the shutdown.button. This also performs a "real" shutdown.

Comment: Incidentally, if you dual-boot, windows *does* close off properly when you call for a restart, but uses hibernate functionality when you do a shutdown, and linux' NTFS drivers will refuse to mount a hybernating windows drive. Something to be aware of.

Comment: @Shadur that bothered me for months and months until I finally figured it out!

Comment: More specifically, you can only mount hibernating Windows drives as read-only in Linux without using dark majicks.

Comment: Not sure why this got to do anything with Linux as Linux wasn't even mentioned in the title or text of the original post. But I have the same issue and don't have that startup power setting, yet some laptops I work with have this and it makes it hard to enter the BIOS since that is totally skipped. :/