# Downgrade to Windows 8 then come back to 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

First the machine is on Windows 10 using the upgrade path from Windows 8.0 to 8.1, then finally Windows 10. Here's the issue. I have a power issue where the machine will not shut down correctly and I have troubleshoot that for 3 days with Internet suggestions and tips. I'm not interested in troubleshooting that any more.

First make a media creation tool for Windows 10 as that is what it is on using this website. Then take the machine back to Windows 8.0 and see if the problem still exist. If it does it is more likely a hardware issue then I have some decisions to make as I troubleshoot the hardware pretty thoroughly. I will then proceed to upgrade to Windows 8.1 which I think I can still do. Then I can use the USB drive from the Windows 10 media creation to upgrade to Win 10.

Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer upgrade to Windows 10 as it has now ended. So a downgrade then upgrade is not viable.

You could however, do a fresh install of 8 without a license and trial it for a day. Then when you are ready install Windows 10 again, install it and it will automatically activate itself. (Because the key is attached to your hardware and Microsoft know because it is in their database)

Comment: Bitten - thanks for the information. My thoughts were to use the Windows 8.0 rescue CD (not actually downgrading) that I made when I first got the system. This should effectively put it to the way the system was from the factory. Then upgrade to 8.1 as that appears to be available. Then use the media creation tool for the Windows 10 update as I do have it activated according to the Microsoft's activation servers.

Comment: Ahh right yes. I understand. Yeah, that should work. It just means that the Windows 8 installed from the rescue disk wont be activated. But at least you can see if it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the downgrade you can install Windows 10 again. During setup skip the entering of a product key, the activation servers detect that you already did the upgrade in the free period and activates Windows 10 again.

Your issue is maybe [related to the fastStartup](https://superuser.com/a/1108401/174557). Try to disable in control panel before restoring your Windows 8. I had to turn it also off on my dads laptop while it worked for him in Windows 8.1.