# System Idle Process started a day ago?

Tags: windows, operating-systems

Today I'm checking the system processes. I checked the System Idle Process and it said it started a day ago. How?? Last night my computer is off, without power. How did it start a day ago? Last night my computer is shut down, powered off and unplugged from the power socket. Anyone can tell what is going on?

Comment: Windows 10 can kinda hibernate by default. Could it be it?

Comment: I clicked the shutdown button. I didn't click that hibernate button.

Comment: I'm talking about [this feature](https://superuser.com/a/1108401/432690).

Comment: Unless you have disabled the Windows "fast boot" feature when you are clicking shutdown it is effectively hibernating as Kamil mentions.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate for now as it is the most likely cause. If you do not have Windows 8 or Windows 10, in which case it may be something else, then you should edit your question to clarify and ask for your question to be reopened.